# ASP.NET 5 and Azure DocumentDb

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way to make Azure DocumentDb work with ASP.NET 5 (Core). I don't need to my application to work with Linux and Mac OS. I tried to target it to full .NET Framework but either I'm doing something wrong or it's not enough but I'm getting an error "the dependency could not be resolved"

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting both aspnet50 and aspnetcore50? I saw a similar issue last year where someone was targeting aspnet50 and aspnetcore50 and their DocumentDB app and getting errors, and by simply commenting out one, the app ran fine.

[image: DocumentDB ASP.NET app targeting aspnet5 and aspnetcore50]

Comment: thanks @Mimi! I'm targeting only dnx451 which I believe is a new name for aspnet50. am I right?

Comment: dnx451 represents the .NET Framework, while dnxcore50 represents .NET Core 5 (5.0) per [http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html) and [http://forums.asp.net/t/2078871.aspx?DNX451+vs+NET+Framework](http://forums.asp.net/t/2078871.aspx?DNX451+vs+NET+Framework)